# How can I find my website's IP address?

Tags: server, ip-address

How can I check my website's IP address? I heard about some free tools that are available on the internet but don't know anything concrete.

Answer (score 3):

**There are multiple ways:**

- If you're in Firefox, open the console (F12), go to the tab [Network], click one of the resources. Then on the right there's "External IP".
- When you use FireBug, tab [Net], it'll give you an IP right away
- You could ping it via commandscreens. On Windows, open Startmenu, and enter `ping example.com` in the searchinput
- Use an [external site](http://get-site-ip.com/) to let them check
- Use a DIG to check the DNS values of the site, could be done via [MXToolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/) or terminals

Answer (score 2):

How do you access your website? If it's by a domain name, such as `www.example.com`, just run a command prompt (in Windows) or Terminal (in OS X) and type `nslookup www.example.com`, which will tell you what IP address that domain name is mapped to.

Answer (score 2):

You can check your website ip with utrace: http://www.utrace.de/?query=nokes.de

The IP can also be queried locally on the computer in command line:

`$ nslookup nokes.de` or `$ ping nokes.de`